# БИТРИКС как вывести свойство Сортировка в шаблоне?

Tags: битрикс

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Приветствую. Интересует вывод в шаблоне разных свойств. в частности Сортировка.

Comment: а о каком шаблоне речь?

Comment: aspro например. или стандартный. template.php

Comment: стандартный что?) template.php это файл шаблона, шаблон к примеру `news.list`, по сути, какие поля будут в `$arResult` решается в `component.php` шаблона

Comment: да, news.list спасибо вам что отвечаете мне.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как выяснили в комментариях, говорится о компоненте `news.list`.

У данного компонента есть параметр `FIELD_CODE`, чтобы в шаблоне появилось поле Сортировка, нужно передать в этот параметр массив со списком нужных полей и поля `SORT`:

```
<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent("bitrix:news.list","",Array(
        "FIELD_CODE" => ["ID", "NAME", "SORT", "PREVIEW_TEXT"], // список полей
        // остальные необходимые параметры тоже не незабываем
));
```

Ссылка на документацию: https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/user_help/components/content/articles_and_news/news_list.php

Comment: Спасибо. А как правильно переменную написать в шаблоне, чтобы вывести?

Comment: ну в `$arResult["ITEMS"]` передается массив элементов, получается что если у нулевого брать, то будет: `$arResult["ITEMS"][0]['SORT']`

Comment: спасибо. как-нибудь проверю. к вам в случае вывода информации платно можно будет обращаться?

Comment: нет, можете тут бесплатно создавать вопросы)